Sort a list of points in row major snake scan order
I have a list of points that represent circles that have been detected in an image.
[(1600.0, 26.0), (1552.0, 30.0), (1504.0, 32.0), (1458.0, 34.0), (1408.0, 38.0), (1360.0, 40.0), (1038.0, 54.0), (1084.0, 52.0), (1128.0, 54.0), (1174.0, 50.0), (1216.0, 52.0), (1266.0, 46.0), (1310.0, 46.0), (1600.0, 74.0), (1552.0, 76.0), (1504.0, 82.0), (1456.0, 80.0), (1406.0, 88.0), (1362.0, 86.0), (1310.0, 90.0), (1268.0, 94.0), (1224.0, 96.0), (1176.0, 98.0), (1128.0, 100.0), (1084.0, 100.0), (1040.0, 100.0), (996.0, 102.0), (992.0, 62.0), (950.0, 60.0), (950.0, 106.0), (908.0, 104.0), (904.0, 64.0), (862.0, 66.0), (862.0, 110.0), (820.0, 108.0), (816.0, 62.0), (776.0, 112.0), (774.0, 66.0), (732.0, 112.0), (730.0, 68.0), (686.0, 108.0), (684.0, 64.0), (642.0, 66.0), (600.0, 70.0), (600.0, 112.0), (558.0, 112.0), (552.0, 64.0), (512.0, 66.0), (510.0, 112.0), (470.0, 70.0), (464.0, 110.0), (420.0, 66.0), (376.0, 68.0), (376.0, 112.0), (332.0, 68.0), (332.0, 112.0), (426.0, 118.0), (1598.0, 124.0), (1552.0, 124.0), (1504.0, 126.0), (1454.0, 128.0), (1404.0, 134.0), (1362.0, 132.0), (1310.0, 138.0), (1266.0, 138.0), (1220.0, 136.0), (336.0, 156.0), (378.0, 156.0), (422.0, 156.0), (472.0, 160.0), (508.0, 154.0), (556.0, 154.0), (602.0, 156.0), (646.0, 156.0), (686.0, 154.0), (734.0, 158.0), (774.0, 152.0), (818.0, 152.0), (864.0, 154.0), (906.0, 150.0), (950.0, 152.0), (996.0, 148.0), (1038.0, 146.0), (1084.0, 146.0), (1128.0, 144.0), (1172.0, 144.0), (1598.0, 170.0), (1552.0, 170.0), (1506.0, 174.0), (1458.0, 170.0), (1408.0, 178.0), (1360.0, 178.0), (1314.0, 178.0), (332.0, 200.0), (382.0, 204.0), (422.0, 200.0), (466.0, 202.0), (512.0, 200.0), (556.0, 198.0), (600.0, 202.0), (642.0, 198.0), (690.0, 200.0), (732.0, 196.0), (776.0, 198.0), (820.0, 196.0), (862.0, 198.0), (908.0, 200.0), (950.0, 196.0), (998.0, 196.0), (1042.0, 196.0), (1084.0, 192.0), (1130.0, 188.0), (1174.0, 186.0), (1220.0, 184.0), (1266.0, 186.0), (1596.0, 220.0), (1554.0, 216.0), (1500.0, 222.0), (1454.0, 222.0), (1402.0, 226.0), (1354.0, 228.0), (1312.0, 230.0), (1264.0, 232.0), (1220.0, 232.0), (1176.0, 232.0), (1128.0, 234.0), (1084.0, 236.0), (1038.0, 236.0), (996.0, 238.0), (950.0, 238.0), (906.0, 238.0), (864.0, 244.0), (818.0, 240.0), (776.0, 242.0), (734.0, 244.0), (690.0, 244.0), (644.0, 242.0), (602.0, 246.0), (554.0, 242.0), (514.0, 248.0), (466.0, 244.0), (422.0, 244.0), (378.0, 244.0), (1456.0, 266.0), (1504.0, 264.0), (1552.0, 264.0), (1406.0, 272.0), (1360.0, 272.0), (1312.0, 276.0), (1270.0, 276.0), (1218.0, 278.0), (1172.0, 280.0), (1128.0, 280.0), (1084.0, 280.0), (1040.0, 280.0), (996.0, 282.0), (952.0, 282.0), (908.0, 284.0), (866.0, 288.0), (820.0, 284.0), (776.0, 286.0), (732.0, 292.0), (688.0, 286.0), (644.0, 286.0), (600.0, 288.0), (558.0, 290.0), (510.0, 288.0), (466.0, 288.0), (422.0, 288.0), (378.0, 288.0), (1504.0, 310.0), (1556.0, 308.0), (1454.0, 316.0), (1406.0, 318.0), (1360.0, 316.0), (1312.0, 318.0), (1270.0, 318.0), (1220.0, 320.0), (1176.0, 320.0), (1130.0, 320.0), (1086.0, 324.0), (1040.0, 328.0), (998.0, 326.0), (954.0, 328.0), (908.0, 328.0), (864.0, 328.0), (822.0, 330.0), (778.0, 334.0), (734.0, 330.0), (692.0, 332.0), (648.0, 334.0), (602.0, 332.0), (556.0, 330.0), (512.0, 332.0), (468.0, 332.0), (422.0, 332.0), (378.0, 332.0), (378.0, 376.0), (428.0, 378.0), (470.0, 378.0), (512.0, 376.0), (556.0, 376.0), (602.0, 376.0), (646.0, 374.0), (690.0, 374.0), (736.0, 378.0), (780.0, 376.0), (824.0, 372.0), (866.0, 372.0), (910.0, 372.0), (954.0, 370.0), (998.0, 370.0), (1042.0, 370.0), (1084.0, 368.0), (1130.0, 370.0), (1178.0, 366.0), (1220.0, 366.0), (1270.0, 362.0), (1316.0, 362.0), (1364.0, 360.0), (1412.0, 358.0), (1460.0, 356.0), (1510.0, 356.0), (1554.0, 356.0), (1504.0, 404.0), (1454.0, 408.0), (1408.0, 406.0), (1362.0, 406.0), (1312.0, 410.0), (1268.0, 408.0), (1220.0, 410.0), (1176.0, 410.0), (1130.0, 412.0), (1088.0, 414.0), (1042.0, 414.0), (996.0, 418.0), (954.0, 416.0), (910.0, 416.0), (866.0, 416.0), (822.0, 416.0), (778.0, 418.0), (734.0, 416.0), (688.0, 418.0), (644.0, 418.0), (602.0, 420.0), (560.0, 420.0), (514.0, 418.0), (468.0, 420.0), (422.0, 420.0), (472.0, 466.0), (516.0, 466.0), (560.0, 466.0), (604.0, 464.0), (646.0, 464.0), (688.0, 462.0), (734.0, 462.0), (778.0, 462.0), (822.0, 460.0), (866.0, 464.0), (908.0, 460.0), (952.0, 460.0), (998.0, 460.0), (1042.0, 462.0), (1086.0, 458.0), (1130.0, 456.0), (1176.0, 456.0), (1224.0, 454.0), (1270.0, 454.0), (1316.0, 454.0), (1362.0, 456.0), (1408.0, 454.0), (1460.0, 450.0), (1412.0, 496.0), (1366.0, 496.0), (1314.0, 500.0), (1272.0, 500.0), (1222.0, 500.0), (1174.0, 504.0), (1132.0, 502.0), (1088.0, 502.0), (1042.0, 502.0), (998.0, 504.0), (954.0, 504.0), (910.0, 504.0), (864.0, 504.0), (820.0, 506.0), (778.0, 504.0), (736.0, 506.0), (690.0, 506.0), (648.0, 508.0), (602.0, 510.0), (560.0, 506.0), (514.0, 510.0), (558.0, 552.0), (602.0, 550.0), (646.0, 550.0), (692.0, 554.0), (734.0, 550.0), (780.0, 548.0), (824.0, 548.0), (868.0, 552.0), (912.0, 548.0), (956.0, 548.0), (996.0, 550.0), (1042.0, 548.0), (1088.0, 546.0), (1134.0, 546.0), (1178.0, 546.0), (1224.0, 546.0), (1272.0, 544.0), (1316.0, 544.0), (1368.0, 542.0)]

I want to sort the points in "snake scan" order like so:

Here is the original image converted to jpg to fit the maximum upload size on SO:

I'm having trouble though because the rows don't have the exact same y value and the columns don't have the exact same x value, it's a non-regular grid.
I tried using the the following function, but it's really sensitive to the tolerance value and doesn't quite work right.
def sort_points_snake_scan(points, tolerance=10):
    """Sort the points in a snake-scan pattern with a tolerance for y-coordinates.

    Arguments:
    - points (list): a list of (x, y) points
    - tolerance (int): the y-coordinate tolerance for grouping points into rows

    Returns:
    - snake_scan_order (list): the points sorted in snake-scan order.
    """
    # Group points by the y-coordinate with tolerance
    if not points:
        return []

    # Sort points by y to simplify grouping
    points = sorted(points, key=lambda p: p[1])
    
    rows = []
    current_row = [points[0]]

    for point in points[1:]:
        if abs(point[1] - current_row[-1][1]) <= tolerance:
            current_row.append(point)
        else:
            rows.append(current_row)
            current_row = [point]
    if current_row:
        rows.append(current_row)

    snake_scan_order = []
    reverse = True
    ind = 0
    for row in rows:
        # Sort the row by x-coordinate, alternating order for each row
        row_sorted = sorted(row, key=lambda point: point[0], reverse=reverse)
        snake_scan_order.extend(row_sorted)
        reverse = not reverse  # Flip the order for the next row
        ind += 1
    
    return snake_scan_order

Here is the result:

Does anyone know the right way to do this?

I'd start by finding the four nearest neighbors of each point. Points in the middle of the image will have neighbors that are approximately 90 degrees apart. The angles to the neighbors give you the approximate slope of the vertical and horizontal lines through that point. You can follow the horizontal line until it reaches a point that has no neighbor in the direction of the line.

would you provide a picture with the starting point of your coordinate system, which was used for the image detection ?

@baskettaz I added the original image to the question.

Have you tried to transform all your coordinates with the slope and to try the snake scan afterwards ? This should reduce the noise, even if not perfect, because you wouldn't be able to track the exact angle (slope) of picture rotation. Something like this

The 5th element of the array is (1408.0, 38.0). What are the meanings of 5, 1408.0 and 38.0?

@CarySwoveland 1408 is the x coordinate of the center of the fifth circle in the list. 38 is the y coordinate of the center of the fifth circle. The origin is the upper left corner. Xs increase to the right and ys increase down.

Note that your data lacks a point on the second row, 8th position, which is also visible in the last image in your post.

I would first sort the data by a diagonal sweep, i.e. by increasing sum-of-coordinates. At each point (in that order) determine what would be a good left-neighbor among the points that were already processed. A good neighbor will be in the ">" shaped cone at its left, and the rightmost candidate. Once attached, the attached nodes form a near-horizontal line, and we only need to consider the rightmost of each line when looking for a match in the ">"-cone of a next point.
This way we build all the lines from left to right. It is then a small task to turn that into a snake order.
Here is a Python function to perform this algorithm:
def sort_points_snake_scan(data):    
    lines = []
    for x, y in sorted(data, key=sum): # visited by a diagonal sweep
        for line in lines:
            x1, y1 = line[-1]
            # Is this point inside the ">"-cone of x,y?
            if abs(x1 - x) > abs(y1 - y):
                line.append([x, y])
                break
        else:  # Not found: this is a point on a new line
            lines.append([[x, y]])

    # sort lines from top to bottom
    lines.sort(key=lambda line: line[0][1]) 

    # concatenate the lines into snake order
    return [
        point    
        for i, line in enumerate(lines)
        for point in (line[::-1] if i%2 else line)
    ]

No need for a tolerance parameter: the algorithm assumes that the grid is not tilted more than 45° (up or down) at any point.

This isn't yet a complete answer but a start on a possible solution.
The following function sorts the coordinates by their y-values and then iterates through them, creating a new row whenever the difference between consecutive y-values exceeds a tolerance threshold. I've set the default tolerance value to 6 as it yields the best initial results.
def group_coordinates_into_rows(coordinates, tolerance=6):
    rows = [[]]
    last_y = None

    for x, y in sorted(coordinates, key=lambda coord: coord[1]):
        if last_y is None or abs(y - last_y) > tolerance:
            rows.append([(x, y)])
        else:
            rows[-1].append((x, y))
        last_y = y

    return rows[1:]  # Exclude the empty first row


l = [(1600.0, 26.0), (1552.0, 30.0), (1504.0, 32.0), (1458.0, 34.0), (1408.0, 38.0), (1360.0, 40.0), (1038.0, 54.0), (1084.0, 52.0), (1128.0, 54.0), (1174.0, 50.0), (1216.0, 52.0), (1266.0, 46.0), (1310.0, 46.0), (1600.0, 74.0), (1552.0, 76.0), (1504.0, 82.0), (1456.0, 80.0), (1406.0, 88.0), (1362.0, 86.0), (1310.0, 90.0), (1268.0, 94.0), (1224.0, 96.0), (1176.0, 98.0), (1128.0, 100.0), (1084.0, 100.0), (1040.0, 100.0), (996.0, 102.0), (992.0, 62.0), (950.0, 60.0), (950.0, 106.0), (908.0, 104.0), (904.0, 64.0), (862.0, 66.0), (862.0, 110.0), (820.0, 108.0), (816.0, 62.0), (776.0, 112.0), (774.0, 66.0), (732.0, 112.0), (730.0, 68.0), (686.0, 108.0), (684.0, 64.0), (642.0, 66.0), (600.0, 70.0), (600.0, 112.0), (558.0, 112.0), (552.0, 64.0), (512.0, 66.0), (510.0, 112.0), (470.0, 70.0), (464.0, 110.0), (420.0, 66.0), (376.0, 68.0), (376.0, 112.0), (332.0, 68.0), (332.0, 112.0), (426.0, 118.0), (1598.0, 124.0), (1552.0, 124.0), (1504.0, 126.0), (1454.0, 128.0), (1404.0, 134.0), (1362.0, 132.0), (1310.0, 138.0), (1266.0, 138.0), (1220.0, 136.0), (336.0, 156.0), (378.0, 156.0), (422.0, 156.0), (472.0, 160.0), (508.0, 154.0), (556.0, 154.0), (602.0, 156.0), (646.0, 156.0), (686.0, 154.0), (734.0, 158.0), (774.0, 152.0), (818.0, 152.0), (864.0, 154.0), (906.0, 150.0), (950.0, 152.0), (996.0, 148.0), (1038.0, 146.0), (1084.0, 146.0), (1128.0, 144.0), (1172.0, 144.0), (1598.0, 170.0), (1552.0, 170.0), (1506.0, 174.0), (1458.0, 170.0), (1408.0, 178.0), (1360.0, 178.0), (1314.0, 178.0), (332.0, 200.0), (382.0, 204.0), (422.0, 200.0), (466.0, 202.0), (512.0, 200.0), (556.0, 198.0), (600.0, 202.0), (642.0, 198.0), (690.0, 200.0), (732.0, 196.0), (776.0, 198.0), (820.0, 196.0), (862.0, 198.0), (908.0, 200.0), (950.0, 196.0), (998.0, 196.0), (1042.0, 196.0), (1084.0, 192.0), (1130.0, 188.0), (1174.0, 186.0), (1220.0, 184.0), (1266.0, 186.0), (1596.0, 220.0), (1554.0, 216.0), (1500.0, 222.0), (1454.0, 222.0), (1402.0, 226.0), (1354.0, 228.0), (1312.0, 230.0), (1264.0, 232.0), (1220.0, 232.0), (1176.0, 232.0), (1128.0, 234.0), (1084.0, 236.0), (1038.0, 236.0), (996.0, 238.0), (950.0, 238.0), (906.0, 238.0), (864.0, 244.0), (818.0, 240.0), (776.0, 242.0), (734.0, 244.0), (690.0, 244.0), (644.0, 242.0), (602.0, 246.0), (554.0, 242.0), (514.0, 248.0), (466.0, 244.0), (422.0, 244.0), (378.0, 244.0), (1456.0, 266.0), (1504.0, 264.0), (1552.0, 264.0), (1406.0, 272.0), (1360.0, 272.0), (1312.0, 276.0), (1270.0, 276.0), (1218.0, 278.0), (1172.0, 280.0), (1128.0, 280.0), (1084.0, 280.0), (1040.0, 280.0), (996.0, 282.0), (952.0, 282.0), (908.0, 284.0), (866.0, 288.0), (820.0, 284.0), (776.0, 286.0), (732.0, 292.0), (688.0, 286.0), (644.0, 286.0), (600.0, 288.0), (558.0, 290.0), (510.0, 288.0), (466.0, 288.0), (422.0, 288.0), (378.0, 288.0), (1504.0, 310.0), (1556.0, 308.0), (1454.0, 316.0), (1406.0, 318.0), (1360.0, 316.0), (1312.0, 318.0), (1270.0, 318.0), (1220.0, 320.0), (1176.0, 320.0), (1130.0, 320.0), (1086.0, 324.0), (1040.0, 328.0), (998.0, 326.0), (954.0, 328.0), (908.0, 328.0), (864.0, 328.0), (822.0, 330.0), (778.0, 334.0), (734.0, 330.0), (692.0, 332.0), (648.0, 334.0), (602.0, 332.0), (556.0, 330.0), (512.0, 332.0), (468.0, 332.0), (422.0, 332.0), (378.0, 332.0), (378.0, 376.0), (428.0, 378.0), (470.0, 378.0), (512.0, 376.0), (556.0, 376.0), (602.0, 376.0), (646.0, 374.0), (690.0, 374.0), (736.0, 378.0), (780.0, 376.0), (824.0, 372.0), (866.0, 372.0), (910.0, 372.0), (954.0, 370.0), (998.0, 370.0), (1042.0, 370.0), (1084.0, 368.0), (1130.0, 370.0), (1178.0, 366.0), (1220.0, 366.0), (1270.0, 362.0), (1316.0, 362.0), (1364.0, 360.0), (1412.0, 358.0), (1460.0, 356.0), (1510.0, 356.0), (1554.0, 356.0), (1504.0, 404.0), (1454.0, 408.0), (1408.0, 406.0), (1362.0, 406.0), (1312.0, 410.0), (1268.0, 408.0), (1220.0, 410.0), (1176.0, 410.0), (1130.0, 412.0), (1088.0, 414.0), (1042.0, 414.0), (996.0, 418.0), (954.0, 416.0), (910.0, 416.0), (866.0, 416.0), (822.0, 416.0), (778.0, 418.0), (734.0, 416.0), (688.0, 418.0), (644.0, 418.0), (602.0, 420.0), (560.0, 420.0), (514.0, 418.0), (468.0, 420.0), (422.0, 420.0), (472.0, 466.0), (516.0, 466.0), (560.0, 466.0), (604.0, 464.0), (646.0, 464.0), (688.0, 462.0), (734.0, 462.0), (778.0, 462.0), (822.0, 460.0), (866.0, 464.0), (908.0, 460.0), (952.0, 460.0), (998.0, 460.0), (1042.0, 462.0), (1086.0, 458.0), (1130.0, 456.0), (1176.0, 456.0), (1224.0, 454.0), (1270.0, 454.0), (1316.0, 454.0), (1362.0, 456.0), (1408.0, 454.0), (1460.0, 450.0), (1412.0, 496.0), (1366.0, 496.0), (1314.0, 500.0), (1272.0, 500.0), (1222.0, 500.0), (1174.0, 504.0), (1132.0, 502.0), (1088.0, 502.0), (1042.0, 502.0), (998.0, 504.0), (954.0, 504.0), (910.0, 504.0), (864.0, 504.0), (820.0, 506.0), (778.0, 504.0), (736.0, 506.0), (690.0, 506.0), (648.0, 508.0), (602.0, 510.0), (560.0, 506.0), (514.0, 510.0), (558.0, 552.0), (602.0, 550.0), (646.0, 550.0), (692.0, 554.0), (734.0, 550.0), (780.0, 548.0), (824.0, 548.0), (868.0, 552.0), (912.0, 548.0), (956.0, 548.0), (996.0, 550.0), (1042.0, 548.0), (1088.0, 546.0), (1134.0, 546.0), (1178.0, 546.0), (1224.0, 546.0), (1272.0, 544.0), (1316.0, 544.0), (1368.0, 542.0)]

print(f"Points: {len(l)}")
rows = group_coordinates_into_rows(l)
print(f"Rows found: {len(rows)}")
print([len(row) for row in rows])

Output:
Points: 312
Rows found: 10
[86, 29, 28, 27, 27, 27, 25, 23, 21, 19]

Clearly this has issues with the first 3 rows, but it appears to have grouped the remaining rows successfully.
Once all the rows are grouped correctly, alternating the sort order for successive rows by the x coordinate will generate the snake order.
def create_snake_order_list(list_of_lists):
    from itertools import chain

    for index, row in enumerate(list_of_lists):
        row.sort(key=lambda item: item[0], reverse=(not index % 2 == 0))

    return list(chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists))

